# Check if cache key exists using redis in node.js application with node_redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have setup an application with `node_redis`, and I am trying to get the simple get/set to work.

It seems I can insert into the cache, but I would like to be able to make a check if the key exists.

In C# I would do something like: `if(Cache["mykey"] == null)` .

How do I make the check? What do I replace `if(!client.get[cacheKey]) {` with ?

**My code**:

```
    app.get('/users',function(req,res) {
    var cacheKey = 'userKey';

    if(!client.get[cacheKey]) {
            mongoose.model('users').find(function(err,users) {
                console.log('Setting cache: ' + cacheKey);
                client.set(cacheKey,users,redis.print);
                res.send(users);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Getting from cache: ' + cacheKey);
        return client.get[cacheKey];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing to note here is that the redis client, like most other things in node, is not synchronous.

The way you are accessing `client.get` implies it's an array in Javascript. It is really a function, like `mongoose.find`, that expects a callback as the last parameter. In this case you just pass `cacheKey` first. Your `if` clause goes inside the callback.

```
client.get(cacheKey, function(err, data) {
    // data is null if the key doesn't exist
    if(err || data === null) {
        mongoose.model('users').find(function(err,users) {
            console.log('Setting cache: ' + cacheKey);
            client.set(cacheKey,users,redis.print);
            res.send(users);
        });
    } else {
        return data;
    }
});
```

If you have any code that followed your if-statement as if it was synchronous, it should most likely also go inside the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like that to get Keys if exist in redis**

```
client.exists('photos', async (err, reply) => {
  if (reply === 1) {
    console.log('exists');
    await client.get('photos');
    res.send(JSON.parse(reply));
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('doesn\'t exist');
  }
});
```

Comment: `await` can only be used inside `async` functions.